# How to prove that the sequence converges to $0$?

Tags: definite-integrals, recurrence-relations

We have the sequence {$I_n$} where $n\in\Bbb N$ and $$I_n=\int_0^{\pi\over 2} e^{-x}\sin^nx\;dx$$
It can be proven that $$(n^2+1)I_n=-e^{-{\pi\over 2}}+n(n-1)I_{n-2}$$for $n\geq 2$.

How to show that as $n\to \infty, I_n\to 0$? The problem is that if we assume $I_n\to I$, we only get $I\to 0$ instead of $I=0$. Is this method always correct?

Comment: Well, the only thing varying with $n$ is the the term $e^{-x} \sin^n x \to 0$, and so the integral of it does too.

Comment: @Tavish: That is a dangerous reasoning and usually not applicable. Only in this case it is true, because $\displaystyle \sup_{x \in \left[0, \tfrac{\pi}{2} \right]} \lvert \exp(-x) \sin^n(x) \rvert \leq 1 < \infty$, i.e. Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem can be used (do you know of this one MathematicalFanatic?).

Comment: "$I_n \to I$" means that $I$ is the limit value of $I_n$ as $n \to \infty$. That is, it is a *single fixed number*. The expression $I \to 0$ does not even make sense, as $I$ is not something that changes.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $e^{-x} \le 1$ on $\left[0,\frac \pi2\right]$, for all $n$, $$0 < I_n < J_n = \int_0^{\frac\pi 2}\sin^n x\,dx$$

$J_n$ has a nicer recursion formula from which it is easy to prove $J_n \to 0$, and the squeeze theorem takes care of the rest.